# Correct way to indent function calls in python

Tags: python, indentation

Suppose I am declaring some variables like this (I think it's too much indentation):

```py
httpd = Server(
    (
        "",
        conf.port
    ),
    Handler
)
```

I could do it like this, but it is not very readable:

```py
httpd = Server(("", conf.port), Handler)
```

or like this (the way in between):

```py
httpd = Server(
    ("", conf.port),
    Handler
)
```

And some people are even doing it like this (which is the worst I think):

```py
httpd = Server(
    ("",
        conf.port),
    Handler)
```

#### Question

Is there any rule / guide which of these variants should be used with which number of arguments ? There is a difference between

```py
var = function(with="with", many="many",
              argu="argu", ments="ments",
              argu="argu", ments="ments",
              argu="argu", ments="ments",
              argu="argu", ments="ments",
              argu="argu", ments="ments",
              argu="argu", ments="ments",
              argu="argu", ments="ments",
              argu="argu", ments="ments",
              argu="argu", ments="ments",
              argu="argu", ments="ments",
              argu="argu", ments="ments",
)
```

and

```py
var = function(argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", ments="ments",
              argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", 
              argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", 
              argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", 
              argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", 
              argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", 
              argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", 
              argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", 
              argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", ments="ments", argu="argu", 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for a guide to these, there is one here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

For your specific case I would recommend using:

```
httpd = Server(
    ("", conf.port),
    Handler
)
```

and group ("", conf.port) on its own line to differentiate it from Handler.

Answer (score 1):

According to PEP8, the line length should be 79 characters. Then, you should wrap any line longer than that.

Though that's only a style guide, not rule or requirement. So it's really up to you. If you use an IDE, e.g. pycharm/atom/vscode. You can set the max length of the lines and use autoformatting to auto wrap the lines. IMO, It's too tedious to to manually.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the indentation is one of the unique programming language feature of Python. But I wouldn't say that there is any correct or right way to call a function with multiple arguments. Most of the time I use function calls with arguments, If the arguments are more than 3, I would use this format:

```
someValue = myFunction(
    first_arg=0, 
    second_arg=5,
    third_arg=10,
    fourth_arg=15,
    fifth_arg=20
)
```

Or I would just use the normal one:

```
someValue = myFunction(first_arg=0)
```

But it is totally up to you. Any kind of format is okay and there is no 'Pythonic' way of doing this.